# Mutex/Multithreading/Shared Resource Issue WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows

I know very little about multithreading, but I am working with someone else's code and need some help as the original programmer is no longer around.

The program has its own exe to run it but the DLL attaches to the process of another program via APIENTRY (WINAPI) ... When the DLL attaches to the process, it creates a couple mutex. The problem is that one of these mutex should only be created once and should be accessible by each process. I can't seem to stop each process from creating its own handle. At the very least, during some operation, I need to be able to pass the handle to the other processes or get each handle from each process and apply the same operation (basically to sync some of the variables). I've tried the old static bool isFirst approach, but each process seems to create a new set of variables so it doesn't work.

I am really confused and frustrated. Any thoughts or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DLL attach mechanism which is called every time a process attaches (sorry I cannot remember the exact name) and separately there is an InitInstance which is invoked when the DLL is loaded. So if you make the mutex handles static globals with the DLL, create and iinitialise the mutex's in InitInstance and hand out the mutex handles to any process that asks for it, you should do better.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Is there a special way to "hand out" the mutex handles? I created a static handle in DLL (lets call it handle1) and did as you advised, then used WaitForSingleObject( handle1, INFINITE ) ... Still, separate processes appear to be using different handles ...

Comment: So. Just to check, in InitInstance you are calling CreateMutex to create the mutex and get the handle, yes? Given that, I would create a function GetMutex(){return g_hMutex;} in the DLL that any of the other processes can call. Are you calling WaitForSingleObject in the DLL? I don't see why you want to do that. The important thing is that any process that has ownership of the mutex via WaitForxxxx **MUST** call ReleaseMutex(hand) to allow other processes to get it. Are you doing that?

Comment: I discovered InitInstance isn't called because it's not MFC. I moved the initialization (g_hMutex = CreateMutex(0,0,0);) into WinMain. The WaitForSingleObject is called within functions in the DLL. Why? I am not sure, the original programmer did this. I presume it's because we actually don't have control over the processes it attaches to (yes, I am confused by this statement, too lol).

Comment: WinMain is fine. WaitForSingleObject as you know halts the thread until it has ownership of the mutex. So there is no reason why the DLL should not use this if it wanted exclusive access to the data that the mutex protects. As long as it calls ReleaseMutex after it is done that's fine. Maybe you don't have control over the processes because, in reality, they are connecting to (attaching to) the DLL...

Comment: Yes, ReleaseMutex is called after it's done. I can see and confirm that WinMain is  only called once while the two processes attach, but they are still acting like before (as if WinMain was called twice/treated as two instances).

Comment: Debugging confirms the handles are different.

Comment: 'the handles are different'. You mean the value of the handle inside your DLL and the handle as retrieved by one process, or is one process getting the same handle value as the DLL, while the other does not? This series of comments is getting rather long - I think we are supposed to go somewhere else on SO - do you know where?

Comment: I was mistaken and looking at the wrong handle. The handle returns a value during initialization but are showing NULL when accessed within DLL. Although MS documentation says if there is an error, CreateMutex should return NULL but the value always seems to be 84 so I am thinking that's an error. Will look into ... I don't know where else we're supposed to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47905/discussion-between-tim-bergel-and-paul)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that separate DLL instances were being created causing separate data segments. I was able to get the handle to the same value across instances using data_seg. I now realize I have a new problem though as I can't use data_seg on the actual variable (vector of objects) that the mutex is protecting from simultaneous writes.